# Why does the value returned by an async function create a promise that resolves before synchronous code?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

#### Take a look at this code:

```
async function fun() {
    return 5;
}

console.log(fun());
```

Here I have tried to return a promise that resolves with value 5, and tried to log the returned object. I was expecting the output to be `Promise{<pending>}` but it logged `Promise{5}`.

#### Then I tried this:

```
async function fun() {
    return Promise.resolve(5);
}

console.log(fun());
```

Now, this gives the output `Promise{<pending>}`. Why is this happening? The fulfillment of a Promise should happen after the completion of synchronous code. Then why am I getting the resolved promise as output in the first case?

Comment: Code in `async` function runs immediately until it finds `await`

Comment: Ok I know that but I am confused about the return statement. Why returning a value creates a resolved promise and returning a Promise creates a pending promise?